# Настройка миниатюры товара на woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы при наведении мыши на миниатюру товара, она немного увеличивалась в размере. В каком разделе это настраивается?

Answer (score 1):

Это не относится ни к woocommerce, ни в wordpress. Это делается с пом css.

Образец кода

```css
.image img:hover{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -o-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
```

См дополнительно: http://htmlbook.ru/css/transform